# Adding a scrollbar to a PanedWindow in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I am a newbie in Tkinter and I am working on creating a graphical user interface.

Basically, I have a main_window (Tk()), which is then split in some tk.PanedWindow() objects. For one PanedWindow (the orange one), I am adding a bunch of tk.Button() objects, too many to be displayed at the same time, so I thought of making this PanedWindow scrollable, using a tk.Scrollbar(). Before I add the buttons, everything looks fine ([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBHjB.png)), but with adding the buttons, the Scrollbar disappears ([img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRVQV.png)).

Here is the code to create the PanedWindow:

```
# divide the left PanedWindow
pw_left_up = tk.PanedWindow(pw_main, orient=HORIZONTAL, bg="orange", width=left_w, height=left_up_h)
pw_left_bot = tk.PanedWindow(pw_main, orient=HORIZONTAL, bg="coral", width=left_w, height=left_bot_h)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(pw_left_up, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

pw_left.add(pw_left_up)
pw_left.add(pw_left_bot)
pw_left.paneconfig(pw_left_up, minsize=left_up_h)
pw_left.paneconfig(pw_left_bot, minsize=left_bot_h)
```

And here is the code to populate the PanedWindow:

```
for i inrange(100):
    btn = Button(pw_left_up, width=button_w, anchor="w", text=button_text)
    btn.pack(fill=NONE)
```

I tried raising the scrollbar using `scrollbar.tkraise()` or `pw_left_up.tkraise(scrollbar)` but it results in an error and nothing visually different.

What am I missing?

Comment: Even if the scrollbar is visible, it won't work. You can't scroll a panedwindow.